# 'npm EER! code 1' When installing dependencies using `npm install --production`

Tags: node.js, linux, git, deployment, npm

I am using flightplan to deploy my node.js application to my server. I run the command `fly production` in my CLI to deploy my app to the server. It does rsync fine, but when it comes to installing dependencies, I get the following error:
[image]

I made sure that I have sudo privileges on my server for this user and npm is definitely installed as it gives the version number when I run the command `npm -v`on my server. I have tried to run `npm install --production` myself on the server as the deploy script does and I get the same error, meaning it is something to do with installing dependencies. Potentially, it could be because in my `flightplan.js`, when it runs the command `git ls-files` to get the files to copy across. it includes all the `node_modules` even though i've made sure that `node_modules` is in the `.gitingore` file.

Does anyone have experience with flightplan npm module/or know why my npm install isn't working on my server?

(I edited out my server IP address from the picture)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I removed the `node_modules` folder by running command `rm -rf node_modules/` then committed this to github, then re-ran `npm install` and then my call to `fly production` worked successfully.